# How do i count and sum the values from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql which holds the values in integers, my table is something like this.

[image]

I want to sum up the values of a particular column, for example i want to calculate the total amount, total cashpaid and total balance. hwo do i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function of MySQL like this:

```
select SUM(amount) from tablename;
select SUM(cashpaid) from tablename;
select SUM(balance) from tablename;
```

OR you can group them into one:

```
select SUM(amount), SUM(cashpaid), SUM(balance) from tablename;
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to do it in one single query:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as total_amount, SUM(cashpaid) as total_paid,SUM(balance) as total_balance FROM tablename;
```

to count element use COUNT()

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename;
```

it's better to use aliases for the column names when using this functions.

Comment: is it? i will be considering to use the aliases then. thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
select SUM(amount) AS total_amount, SUM(cashpaid) AS total_cashpaid, SUM(balance) AS total_balance  from tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select sum(amount), sum(cashpaid), sum(balance) from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

For counting the total number of records use `count()` function.

like:

```
select count(amount) from table_name;
```

It will return from above table in your question 3.

For Sum Use `SUM()` in `SELECT` query.
Like:

```
select SUM(amount) as total_amount,SUM(cashpaid) as total_cash_paid,SUM(balance) as total_balance from table_name;
```

after `as` is your new column name which will automaticaly create after executing of query.